# unable to add limit to the subquery

Tags: join, mysql-5.5, subquery

its my first question, please bear me.
I have following tables

## Item

```
id
name
description
```

## itemPurchaseDetail

```
id
item_id(FK)
branch_id(FK)
purchaseRate
date
```

## Stock

```
id
item_id(FK)
branch_id(FK)
quantity
```

I have to get all the items in specific branch(let suppose branch_id=1), its quantity in stock, its name, its description and its **last purchase rates**. This bold part is smashing my head.

**LINK to fiddle:** [fiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e0263c7a90b7c59053b1b7b700b7b29c)

Comment: Isn't a Date or any order field in table itemPurchaseDetail? How do you know it is the last purchase?

Comment: last entry against each item. but date is also present for every record. you can use that too.

Comment: Please use this fiddle to define your table schema and insert some values, then add the [new] link to the question.http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=68527ab733cc6d7fa9f5b05ade853391

Comment: @McNets i have updated the post with fiddle link. i haven't tried fiddle before so please be lenient.

Comment: I would also suggest that you update your question (and the fiddle) with the query(s) you've tried so far.

Comment: Is there any branchItems table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> select   i.id, 
>          i.name, 
>          i.description, 
>          s.quantity stock,
>          (select purchaseRate
>           from itemPurchaseDetail
>           where item_id = i.id
>           order by PurchaseDate desc
>           limit 1) lastPurchaseRate 
> from     item i
> join     (select distinct item_id, branch_id
>           from itemPurchaseDetail) pd
> on       pd.item_id = i.id
> join     stock s
> on       s.item_id = i.id
> and      s.branch_id = pd.branch_id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  | description | stock | lastPurchaseRate
> -: | :---- | :---------- | ----: | ---------------:
>  1 | item1 | desc 1      |   100 |              222
>  2 | item2 | desc 2      |   200 |              444
>  3 | item3 | desc 3      |   300 |              666
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=81f3e29ea87eb49c7e341fe15aae5aaa)*

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad to help